# Sheets script - Copy Format to Selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to copy the format of a known range to the active selection...

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong?

```
function updateformats() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('DONOTUSE')
  ss.getActiveRange().clearFormat();
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();

  source.getRange('G37:K37').copyTo(ss.getRange(selection), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);

};
```

I expect it should be possible, just can't quite get it to work.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `getSelection()` returns "Selection".

  - So an error occurs at `ss.getRange(selection)`.
- In your script, `ss` at `selection` can be used instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and try to run again.

From:

```
var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
source.getRange('G37:K37').copyTo(ss.getRange(selection), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
```

#### To:

```
var selection = ss.getSelection().getActiveRange()
source.getRange('G37:K37').copyTo(selection, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
```

#### Reference:

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getSelection())

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nish1585 I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

Try changing the last line from this `source.getRange('G37:K37').copyTo(ss.getRange(selection), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);`

to this:
`source.getRange('G37:K37').copyTo(selection.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);`

---

this line: `var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();` is okay since the Sheet class has a getSelection() method or it can be `var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection();` or even `var selection = ss.getSelection();`.  Evidently, where ever it's deployed they all return the users selections for the Spreadsheet.